# Boostrap button overlay

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to overlay 2 buttons (one is circle and another one is normal button). This can be achieved using the CSS below. However I am facing another issue where it's not responsive.  I would like to add 4 buttons in a row ( 2 circles and 2 normal).

And also any elements  which is placed after these buttons not positioned correctly. I.e. if I place a new text in div , the text get overlayed on those buttons.

How do I avoid this? and How can I make this responsive?

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');


.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 35px;
  border-width: thick;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: white;
}


/*Image overlay*/

.container_row {
  position: relative;
}

.background-layer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50px;
  top: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}

.foreground-layer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
}

.btn-lg-overlay {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  border-width: 5px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_row">
  <div class="foreground-layer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>
  </div>
  <div class="background-layer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-lg-overlay"><i>Requested</i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with absolute positioning. Elements that are positioned absolutely are removed from the document flow, they are positioned relative to some other element on the page. This means that they will be "invisible" to the rest of the elements that follow this flow.

When you have wrapper `div`, in your case `container_row`, it automatically adjusts its width and height according to the width and height of its inner elements that follow this document flow. If you position inner elements absolutely, in your case `foreground-layer` and `background-layer` they will not follow this flow and as a result, wrapper `div` will not see them which means its width and height will be automatically set to 0.

If you try to put two buttons one next to another, you are basically trying to put two elements with zero width and height next to each other. This results in them being put on the same spot which makes them appear like they are overlapping.

One way to solve this is to add a specific height and width to your wrapper element.

```
.container_row {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

If you wanna place multiple buttons next to each other, you can float them.

```
.container_row {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not responsive due `width: 300px` given to element `.btn-lg-overlay`
. Plus is the text the hiding behind the circle you should give some `padding or margin` from left

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');


.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 35px;
  border-width: thick;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: white;
}


/*Image overlay*/

.container_row {
  position: relative;
}

.background-layer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50px;
  top: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}

.foreground-layer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
}

.btn-lg-overlay {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  border-width: 5px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_row">
  <div class="foreground-layer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>
  </div>
  <div class="background-layer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-lg-overlay"><i>Requested</i></button>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br><br><br>
<p>TEXT.........MORE TEXT</p>
```